# Recover deleted file after full disk

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems

I was editing a file in nano and, when I saved it, I got a disk is full error. However, when I opened the file again, all it's content was gone, including everything that was there before the disk was filled. How can I recover the file's content? My partition type is EXT4. I've already tried recovering it using debugfs with no success.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Next time, use a version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/); and don't forget backups

Comment: You probably cannot do what you want, at least in the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get my file back by dumping an image of the SD card then grepping the strings output of the block file for "signatures" I remembered of the file. After getting the line number, I just cropped the output and saved it to a file.